# where is factory data reset option on Android 2.3.5?

Tags: factory-reset

Where is the `Factory Data Reset` option on an HTC ChaCha Android 2.3.5 phone? I haven't been able to find the option anywhere, and it is recommended to free up memory, which is short in this phone.

Could it be that I can't do a "Factory data reset" on this model? I am looking at the Settings -> Privacy menu, and I only get:

```
Display message text [x]
Back up my settings [x]
Automatic restore [x]
```

nothing more...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering myself, it seems in this phone is under: "SD & phone storage > Factory data reset."

Answer (score 4):

Whilst this doesn't answer the original question, it is useful information to maintain here. For some older phones (including a non-HTC Android 2.3.4 phone) this setting is found at:

Settings -> Privacy -> Factory data reset

Comment: Could it be that I can't do a "Factory data reset" on this model? See edit.

Comment: This is not the correct location for 2.3.5.  The accepted answer is correct.  Please delete your answer.